# UICollectionView Horizontal - Can't set height less than around 100?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I implemented a UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling. My cells are simply thumbnails (UIImageView) with a size of 50x50.

```
    let cvLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    cvLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    cvLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    cvLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

All works fine, as long as the UICollectionView's height is above ca. 100. If I set its height any lower, the images don't appear anymore and the view looks messed up. I tried playing around with all available settings, nothing changes this.

Does the UICollectionView have a minimum height requirement or is this something I could solve with a Custom Layout?

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: Hmm, could you add a screen shot of what it looks like when you set the height to 100, and when you set it to, say, 90? So we can see what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grasping a straws a little unless you update the question for more detail.  I am going to say it is one of two things.  But most likely the first.

1) You build your layout like in the current question but you never assign it.

```
            let cvLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()         
            cvLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
            cvLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            cvLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            //possibly not assigning it
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout = cvLayout
```

2) you don't have constraints on your imageview but my guess is this is not the case.

Again, I am just taking a stab at it.  If you comment below if neither of these fix the issue I will update the answer provided I have more information.  I can set the height to 50 and it fits perfect.

Comment: Hi thanks, no I did both.
Like I said, it works all fine (including the display and horizontal scrolling as long as the height is ca. around/abouve 100, i.e. I make the images of size 120x120 all works perfectly.

For now, I worked around it by simply giving it a height > 100 and moving other views  sort of over the "unused space". Quite terrible, but works so far.

The layout is quite basic, so I'm pretty confident that there are no other views causing this.

Comment: Do you think that is being squeezed by something else? Meaning other constraints? Where do you think your image views are showing outside of the bounds

Comment: Interesting.  Do you care to share a screen shot of the layout?

Comment: Well, I solved it by putting the CollectionView into another UIView. For some reason that seems to work. In the end I haven't really figured out what the problem was, but still thanks a lot for your help and fast replies!

Comment: Wish I could have helped more.  Weird how some things seem harder than they should be